# Listening the Song End in audio players

Tags: flutter

I wanna ask is there any stream to listen when the song get ended to do some stuff at that point in [audioplayers flutter packag](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers)e or is there any method to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should listen the event [AudioPlayer.onPlayerComplete](https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/b0c84aabea8af28f693941c1b3bf2b1fa1048833/packages/audioplayers/lib/src/audioplayer.dart#L59-L66).

From the docs:

> Events are sent every time an audio is finished, therefore no event is sent when an audio is paused or stopped.

It'd be something like:

```dart
audioPlayer.onPlayerComplete.listen((event) {
  // Do something
});
```

Comment: I am using onPlayerComplete but it is being triggered multiple times so it skips multiple songs at a time. So how did you managed to do it? can you share an example